# Price filter not showing proper price range in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

Magento price filter on category page not showing proper price range on some category pages.

We have set price range Rs.1000 from magento admin section. Most of the categories are showing perfect product price range. For example

```
$ 0 - $ 1k
$ 1k - $ 2k
$ 2k - $ 3k
```

But some are showing categories it price range is coming Rs10k. For example

```
$ 0 - $10k
$ 10k - $20k
```

Please help me with this. If anyone have any idea.